# c#, How would i display the data i am getting from an web service into a grid/table to make it easier to view?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, datagridview, datagrid

I'm very new to c# and web services, and i have been given a task to display this data i am retrieving from this web service in a way it is easier to read, so putting the data into a grid so it separates all the different attributes into columns.
This is the code i have got to retrieve the data, at the moment i have just got it displaying as a string.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new
        RestClient("http://www.dharamhk.com/dharamwebapi/api/StockDispApi/getDiamondData");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", value: "{\n \n uniqID : '...',\n company :'...',\n actCode: '...',\n selectAll: '',\n StartIndex: '1',\n count: '20'\n,\n columns: '',\n finder: '',\n sort: ''\n }", type: ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        Response.Write(response.Content.ToString());

    }

}
```

This is the code i'm currently using just to display the data and to make sure i am fully retrieving all the data.
This is just a small sample of what is returned as there is quite a lot of data:

{"IsValidUser":true,"MessageType":1,"Message":"Get Data Successfully..!!","TotalCount":9606,"DataList":[{"Shape":"ROUND","Size":1.01,"Color":"E","Clarity":"SI2","Cut":"VG"

I want to find out a way to display this data so that it is easier to read and manage.

Comment: You got the data... the rest is up to you how you want to display the data, you can use ASP.NET WebForms controls such as `gridview` and `listview` after you deserialize your json to objects, or you can use javascript library such as `datatables.net` and retrieve the `json` via ajax. Or roll your own implementation.

Comment: Assuming that this is json string, I believe the easiest one (without creating class for this structure) is to download json.net from nuget. Then you can convert this json to DataTable like this:
`var dataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);`
and bind it to DataGridView.